# Does there exist a function with following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Does there exist a differentiable, everywhere concave down function $f(x)$, deﬁned on the whole real line, such that $\lim_{x→−∞}f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x→∞}f(x) = −1$? Give an example justifying that it satisﬁes all these properties or explain your reasoning why such a function does not exist.

It is easy to understand intuitively that such a function does not exist. But how do you prove it?

Comment: Does "concave down" mean convex or concave? That doesn't make much of a difference, it only determines whether you look at $x\to -\infty$ or $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: A number of nice answers to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: a concave function must always lie below a straight line, for instance the tangent line at some point.

Comment: I think I understand that. But, how do I write down a formal solution?

Comment: @AnirudhGangwal Since the function is concave down it cannot be constant, so that tangent line (which the function remains below) must intersect the line $y=-1$ somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If such a fonction exists, then $$\forall x,y, \;\;f\left(\frac 12 x + \frac 12 y\right)\geq \frac 12 f(x) + \frac 12 f(y)$$

Let $x$ be fixed for the moment.

Letting $y\to \infty$ yields $-1\geq \frac 12 f(x) - \frac 12$

Letting $x\to -\infty$ in the last inequality yields $-1\geq \frac 12 - \frac 12=0$, a contradiction.

It seems differentiability isn't even needed.

Comment: Where do you get your first statement from? Could you please elaborate more on the details.

Comment: Uh, definition of concavity  $f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)\geq (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$ with $\lambda = \frac 12$ ?

Comment: Okay. It turns out we weren't taught this exact definition. But thanks anyways. But if you can come up with another answer without using this definition, please share.

Comment: What definition do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If concave down means $f''(x)<0$.  It is not possible if f(x) and f'(x) are continuous everywhere.

$\lim\limits{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1 \implies \lim\limits{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$
Similarly $\lim\limits{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -1 \implies \lim\limits{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$

And since $f(\infty) > f(-\infty), f'(x) > 0$ somewhere in between.

This suggest that there exists some $a,b \, a<b$ such that $f'(a)<f'(b)$.
And by the mean value theorem, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f''(c) = \frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a} > 0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be such a function. As $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=-1$ and $f$ is continuous, we conclude that there exists $c\in\Bbb R$ with $f(c)=0$.
As $f$ is differentiable, let $m=-f'(c)$. 
Then $f$ does not ascend above the tangent line through this point, i.e., 
$$\tag1 f(x)\le f(c)+m\cdot(c-x).$$
As $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=1$, there exists $a<c$ with $f(a)>f(c)$. 
Then from $(1)$ we find $m\ge\frac{f(a)-f(c)}{c-a}>0$.
Then for all $x>c+\frac 3m$, we have
$$f(x)\le f(c)+m(c-x)<f(c)-3<-2$$
contradicting $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=-1>-2$.

Comment: I just see that after much reformulating my first attempt, this ends up as a filled-out version of @Siminore's answer - so maybe all credit should go there

Comment: Nope. Maybe credit should be split, but filling out a sparse answer has definite value, in my opinion.